# validate user input by typecasting

Tags: php, security, validation, casting, web

When I was working on a site navigation, where a GET-Parameter should be displayed on the site itself, I woundered how I could otherwise validate the user input.

The "normal" way would be to convert the input with something like htmlspecialchars() in order to avoid XSS-Attacks. I decided not to convert the input but to typecast it to an int.

The code looks something like this:

```
$siteinfo['current_site'] = (int) $_GET['p'];
```

(of course this is only possible because the expected input is an integer)

What do you think about this? Is it safe? Any disadvantages in your opinion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is safe, assuming that you consider any integer "safe".

Note, however, that an attacker could still try to feed you a zero or a negative value, or a very large value such as 999999999 or (if you're using 64-bit PHP) even 999999999999999999.  If your code tries to, say, run a loop with that many iterations, allocate an array with that many elements, or even create that many database records, it could serve as an easy way to carry out a denial-of-service attack against your site.

Thus, to be truly safe, you should not only coerce the input to an integer, but also verify that the resulting numeric value is reasonable for the purpose you're using it for.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably the safest way to validate an int:

```
$siteinfo['current_site'] = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'p', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
```

Read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that's good, but I would cut it off also:

```
// imagine you need up to four chars
$_GET['var'] = substr($_GET['var'], 0, 4);
```

If it's a text, then I might to this as well:

```
// sample of bad guys
$bad = array('<','>');
$_GET['var'] = str_replace($bad, '', $_GET['var']);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mahdi: both suggestions do not seem very suitable.
The first suggestion treats the input as a string - you use a function that operates on strings. That is all well from a certain standpoint ($_GET only contains strings) but not from the standpoint where you expect the input to be of a certain... form (integer).

The second suggestion also does this (treated as string), but furthermore uses a *blacklist* rather than a *whitelist*. The disadvantage of blacklists is that the risk is high that you forget certain cases. If you go for this approach at all you could make a whitelist in the form of a regular expression check.

Typecasting implies that the original form of the input is, or might be, incorrect. It also might automagically try to fix input.  It's better to explicitly check the input.

user1909426's suggestion seems the best sofar, also taking Ilmari Karonen's notes into mind.